# Solubility of Silver Sulfate in Water

Tags: solubility

Q. What is the solubility of silver sulfate (K_sp=1.77x10^-5) in water, in g/L?

From my own working and other sources, we know that the molar solubility of silver sulfate is 0.0144mol/L. We also know that the molar mass of silver sulfate is 311.796g/mol, so I thought the solution would be m=nxMM=4.49g of silver sulfate per litre of water. However, whenever I google the solubility of silver sulfate at room temperature, it says that the solubility is 8.3 g/L? It seems that I'm out by a factor of 2 - where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Answer (score 1):

The solubility of sulfates is always bigger than what can be obtained from solubility products, because of the hydrolysis reaction between sulfate ions and water like $$\ce{SO4^{2-} + H2O <=> HSO4^- + OH-}$$ As a consequence, for silver sulfate : $$\ce{[Ag+] = 2 \frac{8.3g/L}{311.8 g/mol} = 0.0532 M = [HSO4^{-}] + \frac{[SO4^{2-}]}{2} > \frac{[SO4^{2-}]}{2} = \frac{0.0144 M}{2}  }$$ So, your calculations are perfect. If you do want it, you can even calculate the amount of the sulfate ions that have been hydrolyzed.

Comment: Thank you Poutnik for showing me my ridiculous mistake !

Comment: We all are unbelievably blind sometimes. :-)